# Socket.io emit from client not being received by server

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm going out of my mind on this one because I've used Socket.io before and it's worked fine, and I've boiled things down to a simple test and it's still not working, so I'm really looking for someone to save my sanity here!

I've got the following code on the server-side:

```
const io = require("socket.io");
const server = io.listen(80);

server.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on("ping", function(inData) {
    console.log("ping received");
    socket.emit("pong", { });
  });
  console.log("connected");
  socket.emit("connected");
});
```

Then, on the client:

```
<html lang=""><head><title></title>
<script src="http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  const socket = io.connect("http://localhost");
  socket.on("connected", () => {
    console.log("connected");
  });
  socket.on("pong", () => {
    console.log("pong received");
  });

  function testMe() {
    console.log("Emitting ping...");
    socket.emit("ping", {});
  }

</script>
</head><body>
  <input type="button" value="test" onClick="testMe();">
</body></html>
```

Just for reference, package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Firing up the server with:

```
npx nodemon server.js
```

Load index.html in the browser and I see the "connected" message in browser dev tools as well as in the server console.  Seems good so far.  I click the button, and I see "Emitting ping..." in the console, but that's it.  No message on the server and, as expected, none back on the client either.  Well, at least not for a few seconds... eventually I see a "pong received" message on the browser, which is weird, but I THINK it's somehow timeout-related because I never see the "ping received" message in the server console, so I'm not sure what's triggering that, but given it's like 30 or so seconds later, I'm thinking timeout (note too that this continues to occur, roughly every 30 seconds I see that message, and that's WITHOUT clicking the button at all after the first time - somehow related to Socket.io polling I'm thinking?).

I disabled my firewall thinking maybe it was getting blocked, but is still doesn't work.

I tried this in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Opera, latest version of all four, and no love, so it's not browser-specific.

I thought maybe it was because I was loading index.html directly off the file system, figured maybe a same-domain issue, or possibly CORS (though I didn't really see how and there were no messages like that in the console like you usually see with such issues), so I wrapped it up in Express (after adding Express with NPM of course) like so:

```
const app = require("express")();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get("/", function (inRequest, inResponse) {
  inResponse.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("connected");
  socket.on("ping", function (inData) {
    console.log("ping received");
    socket.emit("pong", { });
  });
  socket.emit("connected",);
});
```

That made no difference, same issue.

I tried using IP address rather than localhost, but that didn't fix it either.

I initially had a copy of socket.io.js alongside index.html but switched to loading it from the server since that seemed more likely to work, but just mentioning this so you know all that I've tried.

I also tried doing the socket.on("pong") line on the client inside the connected callback, which I don't believe is necessary but figured worth a shot, and again, no help.

I'm pretty much out of ideas at this point and this has been driving me crazy for a few hours.  ANY thoughts would be greatly appreciated at this point!

Answer (score 1):

This one took me a little time to catch! Ping and Pong appear to be 'reserved' words in socket.io. I used your exact same code (using express as server) but changed the event names to "testPing" and "testPong" and it worked as expected. Also, link to this issue on GitHub
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2414 regarding 'pong' and 'ping' events in socket.io

Comment: Oh wow, that didn't even remotely occur to me! In retrospect, it maybe should have, but thank you VERY much, that was a crazy one!